# Handling of closures in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, closures

I am using the data.table package to return a list of function closures in a `j` expression as output by the `approxfun` function from the stats package.  Basically, on each Date, I would like a closure that allows me to calculate an arbitrary yval based on an arbitrary xval as determined by `approxfun`.

However, `approxfun` is only valid when there are at least two unique values of x passed to the function. In the case where there is only one unique value of x, I would like to return a function that returns the one unique value of y.

In the code below, I perform this step by check the `.N` value and returning a different function depending on whether or not `.N` is `> 1`.

```
 library(data.table)
 set.seed(10)
 N <- 3
 x <- data.table(Date = Sys.Date() + rep(1:N, each = 3), xval = c(0, 30, 90), yval = rnorm(N * 3))
 x <- x[-c(2:3), ]

 ##interpolation happens correctly
 x2 <- x[order(Date, xval), {
     if(.N > 1){
         afun <- approxfun(xval, yval, rule = 1)
     }else{
         afun <- function(v) yval
     }
     print(afun(30))
     list(Date, afun = list(afun))
 }, by = Date]

 ##evaluation does NOT happen correctly, the val used is the last...
 sapply(x2[, afun], do.call, args = list(v = 30))
```

When evaluating the function 'afun' in the context of the `j` expression, the correct value of 'yval' is printed. However, when I go back after the fact to evaluate the first function, the yval returned is the *last* yval in the group created by the 'by' grouping for the function that is not created by `approxfun` (all the closures created by `approxfun` work as expected).

My suspicion is that this has to do with something I am missing with lazy evaluation. I tried the additional code below using the 'force' function but was unsuccessful.

```
 x3 <- x[order(Date, xval), {
      if(.N > 1){
         afun <- approxfun(xval, yval, rule = 1)
     }else{
         fn <- function(x){
             force(x)
             function(v) x
         }
         afun <- fn(yval)
     }
     print(afun(30))
     list(Date, afun = list(afun))
 }, by = Date]

 sapply(x3[, afun], do.call, args = list(v = 30))
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  Is it something I am missing with base R or something I am missing with data.table?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, typical data.table reference vs copy FAQ. This works as expected:

```
x2 <- x[order(Date, xval), {
  if(.N > 1){
    afun <- approxfun(xval, yval, rule = 1)
  }else{
    fn <- function(){
      #ensure the value is copied
      x <- copy(yval)
      function(v) x
    }
    afun <- fn()
  }
  print(afun(30))
  list(Date, afun = list(afun))
}, by = Date]
#[1] 0.01874617
#[1] 0.2945451
#[1] -0.363676

sapply(x2[, afun], do.call, args = list(v = 30))
#[1]  0.01874617  0.29454513 -0.36367602
```